# Sqlalchemy: Get child count without reading all the children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here are my Parent and Child classes:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    id = Column(...)
    ...

    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent", lazy="select")

class Child(Base):
    id = Column(...)
    parent_id = Column(...)
    active = Column(Boolean(), ...)
```

The reason behind the loading technique of `children` of `Parent` being lazy is that there can be a very large number of children associated with a parent.

Now, I would like to get the number of active children of a parent as a hybrid-property. Here is how I tried to do it:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def active_count(self):
        return len([child for child in self.children if child.active])

    @active_count.expression
    def active_count(cls):
        return (
            select(func.count(Child.id))
            .where(Child.parent_id == cls.id)
            .where(Child.active == True)
        )
```

But the problem with this method is that when I call `parent.active_count`, it fires a query to get all of the children.

How can I get only the count (of active children) without reading whole the children?

Comment: I cannot figure out why `lazy='select'` is best option for you? For me, `lazy='dynamic'` should works as you wish.

Comment: @jorzel Firstly, does that make a difference? I'm trying to get the count without reading whole the children. Secondly, it's said that for web applications `lazy="dynamic" should be avoided: https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/435

Comment: lazy='dynamic' is a great option when you have pagination or have huge collection that don't want to load at once. It is also great option when you want to operate on parent without loading children (if not called explicitely, will not be loaded) @npk

Comment: Updating `lazy="select"` or `lazy="dynamic"` makes no difference in this case; `parent.active_count` will still read whole the children. @jorzel Please read my question again. I will edit the question if it is not clear to you.

Comment: Ok, you must explain this for me this: "but the problem with this method is that when I call parent.active_count". You call active count in a query or in python code outside sqlalchemy context?

Comment: I'm calling it from python code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you unnecessary iterate over children within `active_count` hybrid_property definition. This should works for you:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    ...
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent", lazy="dynamic")

    @hybrid_property
    def active_count(self):
        return self.children.filter_by(active=True).with_entities(func.count('*')).scalar()
        # or 
        # return self.children.filter_by(active=True).count()
        # but it would have worse performance
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit more intuitive to add `.scalar()` to the end of the query, i.e., `return self.children.filter_by(active=True).with_entities(func.count('*')).scalar()` so we can access `example_parent.active_count` directly?

Comment: Of course, my mistake. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip; I use `.count()` everywhere!